# JavaFX Node Snapshot X/Y Params Have To Be Negative

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, snapshot

Execute the test below - the cyan rectangle is displayed centered. That's the intended result. However, why minX and minY of the viewport have to be negative values?

```
public class NodeScreenshotTest extends Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage)
  {
    stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
    stage.getScene().setFill(Color.BEIGE);
    stage.setTitle(getClass().getSimpleName());
    stage.show();
  }

  private Parent createContent()
  {
    BorderPane content = new BorderPane();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50);
    rectangle.setFill(Color.AQUA);    
    SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
    params.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
    // Viewport x/y negative???
    params.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(-15, -15, 80, 80));
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(rectangle.snapshot(params, null));
    content.setCenter(iv);
    return content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The origin (0,0) of the relevant coordinate system here is the upper left corner of the node for which you take the snapshot, i.e. the rectangle in your case. Now you seem to want a border arround your rectangle with a width of 15 raster units. So it's clear that your snapshot has to start at the location -15,-15 and has to have a width and height of 50 + 2*15.